# Question on embedding of a metric space .

Tags: metric-spaces, isometry

State whether the statement below is true or false :
 For every metric space $(X,d)$ , there exists an isometric embedding of $X$ into $\mathbb{R}^4$ .
 Actually, the answer provided is false. I thought about the fact that there are obvious pairs of $(X,d)$ which satisfies the statement like discrete space and some other Euclidean spaces. But can't think of any non-trivial example to prove it false. 
On searching , I came through this :
https://page-one.springer.com/pdf/preview/10.1007/BF01954540
 Please provide me an example and please explain the terms "flat" and "dimensions" in Morgan's theorem a bit .
  Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: Which metric are you considering on $\mathbb R^4$ ?

Comment: @ Gabriel Romon, Sir, the Standard Euclidean metric

Comment: No non-separable metric space can be isometrically embedded in $\mathbb R^{4}$. In particular $\ell^{\infty}$ cannot be embedded in $\mathbb R^{4}$.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy, Sir, can you please suggest me a book explaining "flats" and "dimensions" in Morgan's theorem ???

Comment: Do you think there is an isometric embedding of $\mathbb R^5$ into $\mathbb R^4$?

Comment: I seem to recall that there are $2$-dimensional separable metric spaces that can't be topologically embedded in $\mathbb R^4$ but I don't know an example. But since you asked about isometric embedding, how about a $6$-point set with the discrete metric, $d(x,y)=1$ for $x\ne y$? How would you embed that isometrically in $\mathbb R$^4$?

Comment: So what is your question? You want a "less trivial" example of a metric space which is not isometrically embeddable in $\mathbb R^4$? What does that mean?

Comment: @bof, yes Sir, I want examples apart from the discrete metric, or some examples which are directly using properties of discrete metric i.e. every set is clopen in there etc. Can we construct other examples $(X,d)$ apart from discrete metric so that $(X,d)$ can't be isometrically embedded in $\mathbb R^4$ ?